# Is there a way to make two numbers divisible and print the bigger number

Tags: javascript

I am working on a divisibility problem and need to If make the number divisible by both 2 and 3 it is also divisible by 6 and should print only the division by 6. If a number is divisible by 2 it is sometimes also divisible by 10 and you should print the division by 10. What am I doing wrong here's my code.

```js
    function main(number) {
    if (number % 2 === 0 && number % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("The number is divisible by 6");
    } else if (number % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("The number is divisible by 3");
    } else if (number % 6 === 0) {
        console.log("The number is divisible by 6");
    } else if (number % 7 === 0) {
        console.log("The number is divisible by 7");
    } else if (number % 2 === 0 && number % 10 === 0) {
        console.log("The number is divisible by 10");
    } else {
        console.log("Not divisible");
    }
}


    main(30); // The number is suppose to be divisible by 10
    main(15);
    main(12);
    main(1643);
```

Comment: If you only want to identify the biggest divisor, you will have to put those conditions on top of your checks. Otherwise your code will never reach the relevant check. You are checking for "is disvisible by 6" first. When this condition is satisfied, "The number is divisible by 6" will be logged. The rest will not be considered/executed.

Comment: Thank you for the info I appreciate it but is there anyway you could show me an example of code?

Comment: 30 is divisible by 6 and 10. If you first check whether it is divisible by 6, you will never reach the check for divisibility by 10 as else if is only executed if the preceeding check fails.

Comment: Is JavaScript number `0` is falsy value, `(30 % 2 === 0 && 30 % 10 === 0) => ( 0 && 0 ) => 0`;  which is falsy value, So It did not print your message

Comment: lowest divisible, `function min(number, limit = 10) { let result = NaN; for (let i = 2; i <= limit; i++) if (number % i == 0) result = i; else break; return !result ? 1 : result; }
` height divisible `function max(number, limit = 10) { let result = NaN; for (let i = 2; i <= limit; i++) if (number % i == 0) result = i; return result; }
` **Note:** only divisible by integer

Comment: I get what you're saying Patrick thanks for the info. And Nur thanks for the code I tried to run it and it doesn't seem to be doing what I need it to do ill try to work with it and see if I can get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should control firstly for divisibility by 10 since if block for division control for 6 enters firstly for that number.
**Proof:** Lcm (Lowest Common Multiple) of 10 & 2 = 10 and lcm of 2 & 3 = 6.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the info what you're saying makes a lot of sense I'm going to revise it now and see if I can get it right.